# My first code question! Learning Java and need help performing basic stats on an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This project is all about methods and arrays and breaks down into 3 parts. Firstly, create an array. Second, fill said array with random ints. Lastly, create a method that displays whether each int is even or odd as well as provides the average of the random ints.
Java is my first programming language that i'm being introduced to in my curriculum and I've worked in this issue for about 4-5 hours now but hit a wall. I can't seem to get my statsDisplay method to perform the necessary stats on my created arrays. It appears that since it always results with alternating "even/odd", it's just creating its own array from 1-20 and analyzing that instead of the previous Math.random() array.
Is anyone able to see what might be going wrong here?
Also, this is my first ever post on here so I'm sorry if it's not formatted correctly or asked in an odd way...

```
public class Practicestuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vals = new int[20];
        fill(vals);
        statsDisplay(vals);
        print(vals);
        
        
    }
    public static void print(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void fill(int[] array) {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() *100);

    public static void statsDisplay(int[] array) {
        for(double i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Number is even");
            
            if(i % 2 != 0) 
                System.out.println("Number is odd");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `statsDisplay` method `i` is your iteration counter, not the content of the array. You'll need to check `array[i]` and do your operations on that instead of just the counter

Comment: Also, your code seems to be lacking some curly braces. Speaking of which, while it is syntactically valid to do so otherwise, you should always use curly braces for `if`, `for` and `while` statements.

Comment: In addition to what @OHGODSPIDERS already said, this is a perfect case where using your IDE's debugger would be very helpful. Stepping through your code one line at a time could show you that something about that `i` isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

In your `statsDisplay()` method, the `i` in the `for` loop is the index (1, 2, 3, 4...). The `if` statements are checking if `i` is odd or even. You want to be checking if `array[i]` is odd or even, so you should replace the `i` in the if statements with `array[i]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked and of course completely makes sense in hindsight.

Comment: No problem. I wish you luck (and insight) on your future code.